# PublishSubject `subscribeOn` behavior

Tags: kotlin, rx-java3

Why is the `subscribe` never printing anything here? Just out of curiosity. This is bad practice anyways: I would normally use `observeOn` instead. However, I can't figure out why the `subscribe` is never reached...

```
val subject: PublishSubject<Int> = PublishSubject.create()
val countDownLatch = CountDownLatch(1)

subject
    .map { it + 1 }
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
    .subscribe {
        println(Thread.currentThread().name)
        countDownLatch.countDown()
    }

subject.onNext(1)
countDownLatch.await()
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to decrease the counter before the `println()` statement? Your main thread might terminate earlier than the `println()` statement gets executed.

Comment: True, that's wrong, but that's not the problem. Try to run that code and you'll see it never reaches the `subscribe` anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Why this happens

In the process of *subscribing*, an observer signals its readiness to receive items to the observable via a `Subscribe` notification. See the [`Observable` contract](http://reactivex.io/documentation/contract.html) for details.

Furthermore, the [`Subject`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/subject.html) documentation states:

> Note that a `PublishSubject` may begin emitting items immediately upon creation (unless you have taken steps to prevent this), and **so there is a risk that one or more items may be lost between the time the `Subject` is created and the observer subscribes to it**.

When you call `subject.onNext(_)` *immediately* after attempting to subscribe on a new thread via `.subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())`, the observable (i.e. `subject`) may still be waiting for a `Subscribe` notification from the observer. For example:

```
subject
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
    .subscribe { println("received item") }

// this usually prints nothing!
subject.onNext(1)
```

However, if you add a bit of a time delay before you emit your first item, the observable is much more likely to receive the `Subscribe` notification from the observer before you call `subject.onNext(_)`. For example:

```
subject
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
    .subscribe { println("received item") }

// wait for subscription to be established properly
Thread.sleep(1000)

// this usually prints "received item"
subject.onNext(1)
```

---

### What to do?

If you want all your subscriptions to receive all the items emitted by an observable, you can do one of the following:

- Block the main thread to wait until all observers are subscribed before you call `subject.onNext(_)`.
- Create a new observable that waits until all observables are subscribed before calling `subject.onNext(_)` inside itself.

These might also be of use:

- `ReplaySubject`: This allows you to store a history of all previous items, and re-emit them on each subscription. Downside: you need to store some arbitrary number of items in memory.
- [`ConnectableObservable`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/observables/ConnectableObservable.html): This ensures that an observable only emits items after `.connect()` is called. In particular, the `.autoConnect(n)` operator ensures that the observable only emits after `n` observers have successfully subscribed.

#### Example: blocking the main thread until subscribed

```
val subject: PublishSubject<Int> = PublishSubject.create()
val countDownLatch = CountDownLatch(1)
val isSubscribedLatch = CountDownLatch(1)

subject
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
    .doOnSubscribe { isSubscribedLatch.countDown() }
    .map { it + 1 }
    .subscribe {
        countDownLatch.countDown()
        println(Thread.currentThread().name)
    }

isSubscribedLatch.await()
subject.onNext(1)
countDownLatch.await()
```